# Why the following code compiles with `c++03` but not with `c++11`

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-python

I am using the `boost::python` library in this tiny mwe.

```c++
#include <deque>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

typedef std::deque<long unsigned int>  DequeUInt64;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE_INIT(tmp) {

boost::python::class_<DequeUInt64>("DequeUInt64")
  .def("push_back"  ,&DequeUInt64::push_back)
  .def("push_front" ,&DequeUInt64::push_front);

}
```

I observed that the code above compiles with `std=c++03` and `gnu++03` but not with `c++11` or `c++0x`. The error is:

```c++
tmp.cpp: In function 'void init_module_tmp()':
tmp.cpp:8:47: error: no matching function for call to 'boost::python::class_<std::deque<long unsigned int> >::def(const char [10], <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
     .def("push_back"  ,&DequeUInt64::push_back)
                                               ^
In file included [from /opt/local/include/boost/python.hpp:18:0], [from tmp.cpp:2]:
/opt/local/include/boost/python/class.hpp:223:11: 
   note: candidate: 
       template<class Derived> boost::python::class_<T, X1, X2, X3>::self& 
                               boost::python::class_<T, X1, X2, X3>::def(const boost::python::def_visitor<Derived>&) 
                               [with Derived = Derived; 
                                     W = std::deque<long unsigned int>; 
                                     X1 = boost::python::detail::not_specified; 
                                     X2 = boost::python::detail::not_specified; 
                                     X3 = boost::python::detail::not_specified]
       self& def(def_visitor<Derived> const& visitor)
       ^
   note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
tmp.cpp:8:47: 
   note:  mismatched types 'const boost::python::def_visitor<U>' and 'const char [10]'
          .def("push_back"  ,&DequeUInt64::push_back)
                                           ^
In file included [from /opt/local/include/boost/python.hpp:18:0], [from tmp.cpp:2]:
/opt/local/include/boost/python/class.hpp:233:11: 
   note: candidate: 
       template<class F> boost::python::class_<T, X1, X2, X3>::self& 
                         boost::python::class_<T, X1, X2, X3>::def(const char*, F) 
                         [with F = F; 
                               W = std::deque<long unsigned int>; 
                               X1 = boost::python::detail::not_specified; 
                               X2 = boost::python::detail::not_specified; 
                               X3 = boost::python::detail::not_specified]
     self& def(char const* name, F f)
       ^
   note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
tmp.cpp:8:47:
   note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'F'
     .def("push_back"  ,&DequeUInt64::push_back)
```

My boost is `boost: stable 1.60.0` and my g++ is `g++-mp-5 (MacPorts gcc5 5.4.0_0) 5.4.0`. I can see that somehow the newer standard is causing problems with type/template inference but honestly I don't really understand why? Is the problem because Boost is simply not tested with c++11? What exactly does the error message above mean anyway?

Comment: Just out curiosity, does Clang work?

Comment: I'm surprised the question only has 2 votes. Aside from the title being on the vague side, the question has everything I could want: An actual MCVE, a full compiler error, and context (Boost and compiler versions).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error message gives you a clue:

> unresolved overloaded function type

You pass in `std::deque::push_back`. Looking at a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/push_back), you can see there are two overloads:

```
void push_back( const T& value );
void push_back( T&& value ); // (since C++11)
```

C++11 added a new overload. Therefore, passing a pointer to this as an argument becomes invalid. Likewise for `push_front`. Note that even before C++11, implementations are allowed to add their own overloads<sup>[citation needed]</sup>.

You can cast it to the appropriate type:

```
.def("push_back"  ,static_cast<void(DequeUInt64::*)(DequeUInt64::const_reference)>(&DequeUInt64::push_back))
.def("push_front" ,static_cast<void(DequeUInt64::*)(DequeUInt64::const_reference)>(&DequeUInt64::push_front))
```

I cast it rather than specify the template argument explicitly per STL's [Don't Help the Compiler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKtHxKJRwp4) talk.

You can also use a lambda if you force it to a function pointer first, per Tanner's comment:

```
.def("push_back"  ,+[](DequeUInt64* d, DequeUInt64::const_reference x) { return d->push_back(x); })
.def("push_front" ,+[](DequeUInt64* d, DequeUInt64::const_reference x) { return d->push_front(x); })
```

Comment: Or pass a lambda instead of the unsightly cast.

Comment: @0x499602D2, I was just about to add that :)

Comment: `def()` does not accept lambdas as Boost.Python does not know how to deduce the signature.   Consider using the `+` operator to cast it to a function pointer (e.g. `+[](...){ ... }`). ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b14d632428ed8881))

Comment: @TannerSansbury, Good to know, thanks. Interesting that it doesn't accept them, meaning it should also not accept functors.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that C++11 added an overload to `push_back` to support move semantics i.e. `void push_front( T&& value );`

So the compiler doesn't know which one to pick (`<unresolved overloaded function type>`). You have to spell it out, like this:

```
boost::python::class_<DequeUInt64>("DequeUInt64")
.def<void (DequeUInt64::*)( const T&)>("push_back",&DequeUInt64::push_back)
```